# Another hidden thing... in a word search

Tags: steganography, word-search

Just a simple wordsearch...

```
S W H E N E Y V E R I 
S R E E S O T M E T H 
I N E G S I R K I M M 
E D I T A T E L E L E 
Y G A O U Y W O L B G 
I C N Z B P Q N A A N 
K R Y O E B M E E A A 
S T A L Y R G O M M H 
E R R B I L O G C J C 
D E P U Z Z L I N G X 
S I X T E E N Y W W E
```

The words to be found are:

```
ALL
COMPUTERS
EXCHANGE
HMM
KEYBOARD
ONE
PUZZLING
QWERTY
SIXTEEN
STACK
ZERO
```

Hint 1:

> look in the PSE chat.

Edit:

> that was fast. BG nailed it in like a minute! Looks like I need better inspiration...

Comment: Bit of feedback - puzzles in general should be understandable to all and this involves a bit of context which only a few might understand, I’d say it’s ok because everyone can get the answer they just might not understand it, so probably I’m future I’d use more universal final phrases :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote you are looking for is

> ’Whenever I see something, I immediately go ***BINARY***’ - Beastly Gerbil (me)
>
> Which is something I once wrote in the PSE chat a while back which merrybot seemed to enjoy, enough to make a puzzle anyways.

The word search:

> [image]

And the left over letters give the quote, with a few extra at the end.

Comment: I regret ever uttering those words lol

Comment: That was fast, uh....

Comment: @merrybot word searches aren’t too difficult especially when you’re given the words :)

Comment: Well in *that* case...

Comment: I've another one for you (or anyone)

Comment: The quote you gave is slightly different from the one embedded in the puzzle, which uses "go".

Comment: @LannyStrack My error, sorry bout dat.